# Pseudo inverse (left inverse) of $(I_n \otimes v^T) + (v^T \otimes I_n) $

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse, kronecker-product

Consider a column vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$. We are interested in finding the pseudo-inverse of the following matrix:
\begin{align}
A= (I_n \otimes v^T) + (v^T \otimes I_n) 
\end{align}
where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of dimension $n$ and $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product.

Recall, that the pseudo-inverse (left inverse) of a matrix $A$ is defined as
\begin{align}
A^{+}=A^T (AA^T)^{-1}
\end{align}

**What I tried**
Clearly, if $n=1$ we have that $A^{+}$ is equal to $\frac{1}{2v}$.

I also computed $A^TA$ and tried to find the inverse of it but with no luck.

Comment: Note that $A$ has more columns than rows. If has full rank, then its pseudoinverse is given by $A^+ = A^T(AA^T)^{-1}$.

Comment: $A$ is a fat matrix. $A^+$ isn't $(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$, but $A^T(AA^T)^{-1}=A^T\left[2(v^Tv)I+2vv^T\right]^{-1}=\frac{A^T}{2v^Tv}\left(I-\frac{vv^T}{2v^Tv}\right)$.

Comment: @user1551 how did you get $(A A^T) = 2 (v^T v) I + 2 vv^T$?

Comment: @BenGrossmann  Correct, I will update this.

Comment: @Boby Just multiply them together. You may use the fact that $(X\otimes Y)(Z\otimes W)=(XZ)\otimes(YW)$ whenever $XZ$ and $YW$ are legitimate products of matrices.